# Can I use int8_t instead of char?

Tags: c, warnings, stdint

I made a short code like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
 
int32_t main(int32_t argc, int8_t *argv[])
{
   int32_t i;
 
   if (argc < 1)
   {
      printf("Error\n");
   }
 
   for (i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++)
   {
      printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
   }
 
   return 0;
}
```

And compiled like below, then I see a warning like below.

```
$ gcc -W -Wall main.c
main.c:6:9: warning: second argument of ‘main’ should be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]
 int32_t main(int32_t argc, int8_t *argv[])
```

What is the best practice to use int8_t?

Comment: `char` and `signed char` (what `int8_t` is probably typedef'd as) are distinct types, even if `char` is signed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default

Answer (score 3):

At its root I believe you're asking a style question, which means you're unlikely to get a definitive answer.  Opinions on style are, well, opinions.

Some people believe that you should use C's "natural" types — `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and their `unsigned` variants — most of the time, and that you should use exact-size types like `int32_t` only when you absolutely have to.

Some people believe that the variability implied by the "natural" types is an unrelenting source of bugs, and they believe that you should use exact-size types always.

Now, with that said, the specific case of writing

```
int32_t main(int32_t argc, int8_t *argv[])
```

is objectively wrong, for at least three reasons:

1. On a platform where type `int` is 16 bits, this wrongly declares `main`'s return type, and the type of the `argc` argument, as a 32-bit type.
2. On a platform where type `char` is unsigned, this wrongly declares `argv` as an array of signed character pointers.  That's probably what gcc was complaining about for you.
3. On a more philosophical level, `main` is not a function whose function signature you get to pick.  Somebody else declared `main`, somebody else is calling `main`, your job is only to provide a definition for `main`.  So you simply have to use the types somebody else specified, even if your rule is that you want to use exact-size types whenever you can.  Here, you can't.

Bottom line: Please use one of these two (equivalent) forms for `main` with arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Unless you're writing "freestanding" code, anything else is confusing, misleading, nonstandard, or wrong.  (It's also acceptable to define a `main` that takes no arguments.)

> What is the best practice to use int8_t?

I would say, when you really, really need a tiny, 8-bit, signed integer, or perhaps when you're manipulating memory as signed bytes.  But I would not go using `int8_t` instead of `char` everywhere, because it's going to cause you lots of problems, and it's not going to buy you anything.

Comment: This is **not** a style question. More precisely: `int8_t` is likely an alias for `signed char` which is a different type from `char` even if `char` is signed by default.

Comment: The standard contains the text "...or equivalent" which is clarified by a foot note "Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as
char ** argv, and so on."

Comment: @chqrlie The question's title is a style question.  The specific example concerning `main` is not.

Comment: I agree to this is style question. Actually, I like the style to use exact size type instead of natural/traditional ones. But as mentioned earlier, I cannot use it int8_t for main(). And that was bothering me even though main() is only one case I have a problem. So, it means the best practice is accept main() as an exceptional case. It seems.

Comment: @Cprogrammer: I would argue that best practice is to use standard prototypes unchanged for `main` and all library functions.  It is also advisable to use `char` for actual characters used for text as opposed to `int8_t` and `uint8_t` for signed and unsigned bytes read from binary contents.  String literals should be considered `const` and manipulated via `const char *`.  Code should behave in a defined manner regardless of the signedness of the `char` type. This is not just a question of style, it is a sane habit to improve readability and sturdiness, avoid confusion and some mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

What you have posted is an implementation-defined form of `main()`. It is only allowed in two cases:

- Either it is 100% compatible with `int main (int argc, char** argv)`, or
- It is an implementation-defined form that the compiler documentation have told you is fine to use.

It is the C standard and the compiler which decide the acceptable forms of main(), never the programmer.

Notably `int8_t` may or may not be compatible with `char`, since `char` has implementation-defined signedness.

Comment: Even if `char` is signed by default, `signed char` and `char` are different types.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes but the are compatible types if they have the same signedness. "The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called the character types. The implementation shall define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char."

Comment: @Lundin But being different types, a `char**` is incompatible with a `signed char**`. And regardless, them being different types means the `main` function definition isn't a valid standard one.

Comment: @Kevin `main()` can have various signatures `int main(void)`, `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, the equivalent or _some other implementation-defined manner_.  `signed char **argv` is not certainly invalid, but may be.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Fair enough. I didn't realize that implementations were allowed to provide other valid signatures for main: [`/* another implementation-defined signature */ `(since C99)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function)

Comment: @Kevin: the classic implementation-defined alternative signature is `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best practice to use int8_t?

When you need a very small signed integer. That's not the same as `char`. `char` comes in three flavours:

```
signed char
unsigned char
char
```

If you *know* you want a signed `int8_t`, use it. If you are dealing with standard string API:s, like `main`, use `char`.

`int8_t` doesn't even need to exist. It's implementation specific. There are platforms where it doesn't exist.

The same goes for `int32_t` that you use instead of `int`. It doesn't necessarily exist and even if it does, it's not always a `typedef` for `int` - so use `int` if you want to stay portable.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach has many drawbacks:

- the prototype for `main()` is not compatible with any of the standard ones, even if `int` has 32 bits and if `char` is signed because `char` and `signed char` are different yet compatible types but `char *` and `signed char *` are incompatible types.
- if `int` is not the same as `int32_t`, the prototype is definitely incompatible with the standard one and the behavior is undefined.
- `printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);` would have undefined behavior if type `int` is not exactly the same as `int`.  You could use the macros from `<inttypes.h>`, but they are rather cumbersome and would be the code less readable.

Hence the prototype for your `main` function should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and for consistency, `i` should be defined with the same type as `argc`: `int`.

The resulting code is quite simple and readable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
 
    if (argc < 1) {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
 
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

I would argue that best practice regarding `int8_t` vs `char` is to use standard prototypes unchanged for `main` and all library functions. It is also advisable to use `char` for actual characters used for text as opposed to `int8_t` and `uint8_t` for signed and unsigned bytes read from binary contents. String literals should be considered `const` and manipulated via `const char *`. Code should behave in a defined manner regardless of the signedness of the char type. This is not just a question of style, it is a sane habit to improve code readability and sturdiness, avoid confusion and some mistakes.